# .Q.hg fails with Protocol not available error

Tags: kdb

I am trying to download some historical financial data using `.Q.hg` from this link: `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=5min&apikey=demo`. I get a `'conn: OS reports: Protocol not available`.

I checked my `openssl` version as I know `kdb` is fussy about the `openssl` version. I downgraded to 1.0.* and tried again ... same error.

I assume it's something to do with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but not 100%.

I checked `-26!()` and I get the following error: `'Could not initialize openssl. Error was libssl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Anyone has any ideas how to sort this out?

Cheers!

UPDATE: I'm on Linux Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

UPDATE: 
I ran `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev` and downgraded the openssl library to 1.0* 
I have also upgraded kdb to 64bit

The new error on `-26!()` is `'Could not initialize openssl. Error was incompatible ssl version`.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: reinstalled openssl and modified the name of the libssl.so to be picked up by kdb. I still get the protocol unavailable error. I think it is caused by SLL_CERT_FILE and SSL_KEY_FILE not being set up correctly.

Comment: Would you mind describing your platform? Cpu, Os, versions...

Comment: I have added the details you have requested. I am pretty sure now that I don't have the certificates properly set up. Any idea how I can set them up

Comment: You should read some documentation to find out which version of OpenSSL this Qhg wishes to use.

Comment: From what I know I think it is 1.0.*. I got the -26!() To work. Instill get a protocol not available error and so assume that's caused by ssl_cert_file and ssl_key_file not working properly.

Comment: https://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/ssl/#tls-client-mode has instructions for setting up the client certificates, have you followed these?

Comment: Kind of. Not sure how the makeCerts.sh work . I'm not sure what to change in that script to make it work for my example.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `makeCerts.sh` - that is for TLS *server* mode, you want to follow the instructions for *client* mode i.e. setting `SSL_CA_CERT_FILE` env var rather than `SSL_CERT_FILE`. The link I posted should take you to the client mode instructions